# Displaying coloured text in a RichTextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

so i have a string of characters that are typically formatted like this:

" t**e**xt" where the bold character is red.

i want to display these types of strings in a richtextbox with the **bold** character being red.

i have the text in a string variable and i have the location of the red character (in the string) in an int variable.

my solution is:

- get characters  before the red character
- get red character
- get characters after the red character
- display characters before the red character
- display red character (with foreground = Brushes.Red)
- display characters after the red characters

this is what i've got so far:

https://github.com/icebbyice/rapide/blob/master/rapide/SpreadWindow.xaml.cs

find: "//stackoverflow" (also, seperateOutputs is not completed)

i stopped there because i thought there had to be a more efficient way to do it because i will be changing the content of the rich text box often (up to 1000 content changes / 60 seconds).

so, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Rich text is very verbose no matter how you look at it. Depending on how big your rich text box is, maybe using a WebBrowser and using html might be more robust and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
// getting keywords/functions
string keywords = @"\b(e)\b";
MatchCollection keywordMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, keywords);

// saving the original caret position + forecolor
int originalIndex = codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart;
int originalLength = codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength;
Color originalColor = Color.Black;

// MANDATORY - focuses a label before highlighting (avoids blinking)
menuStrip1.Focus();

// removes any previous highlighting (so modified words won't remain highlighted)
codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = codeRichTextBox.Text.Length;
codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;

// scanning...
foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)
{
    codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
    codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
    codeRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(codeRichTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

// restoring the original colors, for further writing
codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = originalIndex;
codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = originalLength;
codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;
codeRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(codeRichTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

// giving back the focus
codeRichTextBox.Focus();
```

That belongs in the `RichTextBox` `TextChanged` `Event`

If you type **e**, it will display it **Bold**. Any other text will be displayed as `Font.Regular`

If you would like to change the syntax from **e**, then look at the `keywords` `string`

This is all I have for this, I hope it helps you :)